# Создание формы

Tags: java, форма

Как можно создать форму для текста без использования `Swing`? мне надо было создать `TabSheet` и туда добавить несколько вкладок `Table` и в каждой вкладке должны быть формы для заполнения . как это сделать?

```
TabSheet tabsheet;  
  Table queryTable;
    protected Component buildQuickView() {
    tabsheet = new TabSheet();
    tabsheet.setSizeFull();
    tabsheet.addStyleName(StyleName.ESP_LIST_FORM_QUICKVIEW);   
    buildQueryTable();
    tabsheet.addTab(queryTable, "Запросы");
    return tabsheet;
  }

private void buildQueryTable(){
          queryTable=new Table();
          queryTable.addStyleName(StyleName.ESP_LIST_FORM_TABLE);
          queryTable.setSizeFull();
          queryTable.setColumnCollapsingAllowed(true);
        }
```

Как добавить формы в `queryTable`?

Comment: а почему нельзя использовать swing?

Answer (score 1):

Если нельзя использовать Swing, используйте AWT или JavaFX. *Ваш К. О.*